# Create a data structure with the features of an array in the constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I want to create a special list data structure that works like an array, in that it's like a list with values x[0], x[1], ... Any advice would be much appreciated.

I know all of my code isn't perfect I just want to figure out how to fix the one problem I've outlined below. This is some of the code I have:

```
public class SpecialList {

int[] specialList;
int lengthList;


public SpecialList(int x[]) {
    this.lengthList = x.length;
    this.specialList = new int[lengthList];
    this.specialList = x;
    for (int i=0; i<lengthList; i++) {
        this.specialList[i] = x[i];
    }
}

public SpecialList(SpecialList w) { 
    this.specialList = w.specialList;
}

public SpecialList doSomething(SpecialList y) { 
    int len = y.lengthList;
    //The line below is an example to show the error I get
    System.out.println(y[0]);
    //Do some other stuff to the list y
    return y;
}

//I test the code with this
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpecialList y = new SpecialList(new int[] {14, 17, 30});
    SpecialList z = x.doSomething(y);
}
```

However I get the error 'array required, but SpecialList found' when I try to do stuff with `y[i]` like with `System.out.println(y[0]);` line of code.

'`lengthList`' works but getting the individual values of `y[i]` , the list doesn't. I cant work out whats wrong with my constructor for it to not work how I want it to.

Comment: You can't. You either have to expose the internal array or use a getter similar to how an ArrayList functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redefine what `[n]` means based on what object it's applied to; that's an *array-specific* notation. So `y[0]` where `y` is a `SpecialList` instance just won't work. If it could work, [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (or at least [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or other implementions where direct addressing is cheap) would probably have that feature.

Although you can do that in some other languages, you can't in Java. It's just not a feature Java offers. *(Which is a good thing or a bad thing depending on your point of view...)* Instead, you'll have to provide [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) and [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,E)) methods or similar, just like `List` does.